# Is this normal Entity Framework behaviour

Tags: oop, entity-framework-4.1, one-to-many

I have two one to many relations between the following classes

```
public class SiteMember
{
        public int SiteMemberID { get; set; }
        public virtual List<FriendshipInvitation> InvitationsSent { get; set; }
        public virtual List<FriendshipInvitation> InvitationsReceived { get; set; }
}

public class FriendshipInvitation
{
        public int InvitingUserID { get; set; }
        public SiteMember InvitingUser { get; set; }

        public int InvitedUserID { get; set; }
        public SiteMember InvitedUser{ get; set; }
}
```

Then in controller I have the following code (which loads one SiteMember from db):

```
SiteMember sm = repoSiteMember.GetUserByName(User.Identity.Name);
```

at this point

```
sm.InvitationsReceived.InvitingUserId = 1;
sm.InvitationsReceived.InvitingUser = null
```

Then I have the following line (which loads all SiteMembers from db):

```
IEnumerable<SiteMember> all = repoSiteMember.GetAll();
```

after which

```
sm.InvitationsReceived.InvitingUserId = 1 
sm.InvitationsReceived.InvitingUser = proxy to SiteMember object.
```

My question is: Is this normal behaviour? I'm quite sure I can "fix" null pointer with include statement, but I find it weird that loading all elements from db actually changes the state of object. (null => proxy). Should the proxy be there from the beginning?

**Edit:**
Just to confirm, include statement does solve the problem of null reference, but that was not the question here.

```
DataContext.Members
   .Include("InvitationsSent.InvitedUser")
   .Include("InvitationsReceived.InvitingUser")
   .FirstOrDefault(e => e.UserName == userName);
```

**Edit2:** Methods included now.

```
public SiteMember GetUserByName(string userName)
{
    return base.DataContext.Members.FirstOrDefault(e => e.UserName == userName);
}

public IEnumerable<SiteMember> GetAll()
{
    return base.DataContext.Members.ToList();
}
```

**Edit3:** You may need that to recreate the model.

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<FriendshipInvitation>()
        .HasRequired(e => e.InvitedUser)
        .WithMany(e => e.InvitationsReceived)
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.InvitedUserID)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<FriendshipInvitation>()
        .HasRequired(e => e.InvitingUser)
        .WithMany(e => e.InvitationsSent)
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.InvitingUserID);


    modelBuilder.Entity<FriendshipInvitation>()
        .HasKey(e => new { e.InvitingUserID, e.InvitedUserID, e.InvitationNo });
```

Comment: This is not many-to-many. It is two one-to-many associations.

Comment: Excuse me sir. I have a cold. Of course it is. Thank you.

Comment: How could anyone give an answer when you hide the most important part of the code behind two custom method calls - `GetUserByName` and `GetAll`?

Comment: @Slauma, code for custom methods included. Thanks for raising that.

Comment: And `FriendshipInvitation.InvitingUser` really isn't `virtual`? I'm wondering how it could ever be a dynamic proxy...

Comment: It really isn't virtual and it really is a dynamic proxy :) {System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.SiteMember_36A7C1CDACB6383A7C084C67F194FE298871514728A451FB4E4F1D87553EF795} Would you like a screenshot?

Comment: No, no screenshot. My world view is wrecked, I am going to test your model ...

Comment: I added edit 3 that contains fluent API to create the model.

Comment: Thanks for the mapping, I had already figured it out during test. My world view is in line again, see my answer :) And +1 for the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the different behaviour is normal and it occurs because of *Relationship Fixup*.

When you load only one `SiteMember` with `FirstOrDefault` the two collections `InvitationsSent` and `InvitationsReceived` will be loaded as well as soon as you access them (or inspect them in the debugger) because they are marked as `virtual` and lazy loading will apply. But the `FriendshipInvitation`s in those collections won't lazily load the `InvitingUser` or the `InvitedUser` because these navigation properties are *not* marked as `virtual`.

Say, `SiteMember` 1 that you load with `FirstOrDefault` has an invitation received from `SiteMember` 2 and no invitation sent. So, `InvitationsReceived` will contain one element and `InvitationsSent` will be empty. That element - a `FriendshipInvitation` entity - will have `InvitingUser` as 2 and `InvitedUser` as 1. The `InvitingUser` will be `null` in that case because it can't be lazily loaded (since it isn't `virtual`) and the `SiteMember` 2 isn't loaded yet into the context. (`InvitedUser` however will be a dynamic proxy to `SiteMember` 1 because you already have loaded the `SiteMember` 1, see next paragraph.)

However, if you load *all* `SiteMember`s with `ToList()` the `SiteMember` 2 will be loaded as well into the context with the query executed by `ToList()`. EF will set the `InvitingUser` 2 automatically to the already loaded entity which is called *Relationship Fixup*. It is *not* loaded by lazy loading of the `InvitingUser` navigation property because lazy loading isn't supported for a not `virtual` property.

To have a consistent behaviour and not rely on Relationship Fixup alone I would suggest that you mark the `InvitingUser` and `InvitedUser` navigation properties as `virtual` as well.

Comment: That is an excellent explanation. I didn't know about Relationship Fixup. I have subsequently changed these properties to virtual to avoid logical, but not obvious behaviour of objects. Thank you very much for your help.